# How to connet many points in Polygon

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, polygon

I have a problem with connecting many points in a polygon. I have a list of points and I want the result to be something like this: http://imageshack.us/a/img818/6663/punktyx.jpg

Comment: Is this always convex? Then you are looking for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: Have you googled for some algorithms? Have you tried to do something? What is the data structure where you hold your points?

Comment: if i understand the question, you want the outer points connected?

Comment: Yes I tried. I have  List<Point> and I draw in Grid in WPF, Polygon.  Majid Max - Yes

Comment: As @Sebastian has said already, you have to calculate the convex hull. WPF won't do that for you.

Comment: Now I am looking for information about convex hull.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I won't spit code for that...

Basicly, you know at least 4 points that will always be part of that polygon: Min and Max in X, Min and Max in Y. If two or more points has the same Min or Max, they will be connected.

For the following calcul, assume that each point is a Vector3, where Z is 0.

Using MinX and MinY, you need to connect them with other points. Doing a Cross Product of (MinX - Point), (Point - MinY), if the Z of the resulting vector is +1, the point is creating a hull shape when connected with MinX and MinY. After parsing all point, you are left with a collection of point that are potentially valid, each would create a convex shape. From them, you retake the MinX/MinY again and reparse the remaining points. If MinX and MinY is the same point, you know it directly links to others.

Basicely, you do that for the 4 quandrants. (MinX/MinY, MinX/MaxY, MaxX/MinY, MaxX/MaxY)

You will end up with a list of point that define the outter shape or a convex hull. From that, should be simple enough to connect them.

There's probably an algo that would be more efficient, just saying how I would do it.